# Angular + Node - How to check for authenticated user using Auth Guard

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to check if the using is Authenticated by making a request to the back-end api with the jwt headers present. If they are the user is returned if not it will return unauthorized.

The problem i have is the auth.guard is fired and returns undefined in the console.log because the auth.service has not finished querying.

auth.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {


  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }


  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {

    console.log(this.authService.isAuthenticated());

    if (this.authService.isAuthenticated()) {
      return true;
    }

    this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
    return false

  }
}
```

auth.service.ts

```
import { JwtService } from './jwt.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  user: any;

  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService,
    private jwtService: JwtService,
    private userService: UserService) {


      this.getAuthenticatedUser().subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.user = res;
      }, (error) => {
        this.user = null;
      });


  }

  login(credentials) {

    let endpoint = 'auth/'

    return this.apiService.post(endpoint, credentials)
      .map(res => {
        this.jwtService.saveToken(res.data.jwtToken);
        window.localStorage.setItem('user_id', res.data.user._id);
      });
  }

  logout() {

  }


  isAuthenticated() {
    return this.user;
  }

  getAuthenticatedUser() {

    let endpoint = 'auth/'

    return this.apiService.get(endpoint);
  }

}
```

Whats is the best implementation here to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify this by adding a localstorage session. Once the user is authenticated you can store the token in localstorage and in authguard service you can check the status.

For example:

You could create a class with login user info as follows,

```
export class LoginInfo {
    username: string;
    role: string;
    token: string;
    isLoggedIn: boolean;
}
```

and in your **`authservice.ts`**

```
 login(username: string, password: string): Observable<LoginInfo> {
        const url = `${environment.apiUrl}/token`;
        const params = 'username=' + username + '&password=' + password + '&grant_type=password';
        const headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
        });
        return this.http.post(url, params, { headers: headers, withCredentials: true })
            .map((response: Response) => {
                console.log(response);
                const token = response.json() && response.json().access_token;
                if (token) {
                    this.tokenInfo = this.decodeToken(token);
                    this.loggedInfo = new LoginInfo();
                    this.loggedInfo.role = this.tokenInfo.Role;
                    this.loggedInfo.token = token;
                    this.loggedInfo.username = username;
                    this.loggedInfo.isLoggedIn = true;
                    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                    localStorage.setItem('loggedInfo', JSON.stringify(this.loggedInfo));
                    return this.loggedInfo;
                } else {
                    return this.loggedInfo;
                }
            },
            err => console.log(err));
    }
```

and in your **`auth-guard.service.ts`**

you can simply check the token and redirect to login if the token is not present

```
canActivate() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('loggedInfo')) {
        return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: My question is, whats preventing someone from adding a manual loggedInfo item in the localstorage and setting it to any value. The canActivate function will return true once it simply finds the item.

Comment: @KHAN you should use token here! you should check both token and isloggedin to be true

Comment: What do you mean by check both to be true? if you mean check that they are both present items in the local storage, then i would still have the same problem. The integrity of the local items can be altered/added, so i assumed my only option was to make a call to the back end each time...

Comment: @KHAN i think you are not getting my point, if you are using a jwt token, you could check for the authentication on the client side (localstorage) itself. even if the token is altered in localstorage, your other requests will fail. its not a good practice to call each time to check authentication

Comment: thats how my implementation is right now for the auth guard. It calls a backend GET Auth/ endpoint with the jwt headers taken from the localstorage. if success it returns the user, if false it returns unauthorized. - But you're saying i should not do this with AuthGuard, but let a user pass in and any requests they make it will be checked by the jwt anyway.