# Angular - Authentication Service As A Singleton

Tags: angular

I tried to follow this answer to make my Auth Service a singleton. [Angular Service is reset on each call of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44361707/angular-service-is-reset-on-each-call-of-it?rq=1).

When a user logs in, i set a isLoggedIn variable in my AuthService, hoping to maintain this state. However when i navgiate to a restricted route such as /main. The variable is returning back false in my console when the user is infact logged in.

What am i doing wrong here?

**auth.service.ts**

```ts
import { JwtService } from './jwt.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  user: any;
  isLoggedIn: boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private apiService: ApiService,
    private jwtService: JwtService,
    private userService: UserService) {
  }

  login(credentials) {

    let endpoint = 'auth/'

    return this.apiService.post(endpoint, credentials)
      .map(res => {
        this.jwtService.saveToken(res.data.jwtToken);
        window.localStorage.setItem('user_id', res.data.user._id);
        this.user = res.data;
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
      });
  }

  logout() {

  }

  isAuthenticated(): boolean {return this.isLoggedIn};

}
```

**auth.guard.ts**

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {


  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }


  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {


    console.log(this.authService.isAuthenticated());
    if (this.authService.isAuthenticated()) {
      return true;
    }


    this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
    return false

  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';


import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';

import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component'
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { MainComponent } from './components/main/main.component';


import {ApiService} from './services/api.service';
import {JwtService} from './services/jwt.service';
import {UserService} from './services/user.service';
import {SharedModule} from './shared/shared.module';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    LoginComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [
    ApiService,
    JwtService,
    UserService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

**shared.module.ts**

```ts
import {ModuleWithProviders, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {MaterialModule} from './material.module';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from "@angular/flex-layout";

import {AuthGuard} from '../guards/auth.guard';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MaterialModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    
  ],
  exports: [
    MaterialModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,    
  ]
})

export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [
        AuthService,
        AuthGuard,
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

main.module.ts (restricted by auth.guard, for logged in users only)

```ts
import { NgModule }       from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }   from '@angular/common';

import {MainComponent} from './main.component'
import {ChatComponent} from '../chat/chat.component';
import {MomentsComponent} from '../moments/moments.component';
import {SettingsComponent} from '../settings/settings.component';
import {QuestionsComponent} from '../questions/questions.component';
import { SearchComponent } from '../search/search.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import {SharedModule} from '../../shared/shared.module';


import { MainRoutingModule }       from './main-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MainRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    FormsModule,
    
  ],
  declarations: [
    MainComponent,
    ChatComponent,
    MomentsComponent,
    SearchComponent,
    SettingsComponent, 
    QuestionsComponent,
  ]
})
export class MainModule {}
```

Comment: is the page getting refreshed?

Comment: yes the page is being refreshed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the page is refreshed , even though angular service is singleton, the values will be lost on page refresh.

Alternatively, you could just change the route without refreshing the page. Or you could store the **`LoginStatus`** on **`localstorage`** variable and get information on other pages if you really want the page refresh to happen

```
this.isLoggedIn = true;
localStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', 'true');
```

Comment: Im having trouble then deciding what the best method is to get the authenticated user. if you see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46631207/angular-4-node-how-to-check-for-authenticated-user-using-auth-guard i'm not able to call the backend service in time to check if the user is authenticated

Comment: Provide services(auth/guard) in the app.module Instead of shared module

Comment: @KHAN if you are dealing with token , you dont have to make another call to check if user is authenticated.  i have answered the question